# ssh agent give me a warning for a fingerprint it has already stored in known_hosts

Tags: ssh

When I try to ssh copy a file to my web server, I get the following message:

```
The authenticity of host 'xxxxxx' can't be established
```

But the RSA key it prints me is the same I have when I run: `ssh-keygen -l -f ~/.ssh/known_hosts` (well, I've got this one two times but I don't know what's associated with). Strangely, doing a 'ssh user@host' just proceed normally.

For my little experience, I can't figure out what's going on, and for the most documentation and tutorial I've read, I can't remember that I would have had to add my host fingerprint several times.

Would anyone have an explanation for the noob I am?

---

Okay, I finally solved it, but I don't really know why. My try was that command:

```
sudo scp -rpP 2222 '/media/user/DATA/Mes programmes/alpine5' user@host:/home/user
```

Deleting the sudo resolved my problem (I put it there because I first tried to reach a folder (on my server) where user's permission was denied, which I realize now is terribly wrong). Also I denied ssh login as root in my sshd_config file, so it couldn't work (but I still don't understand why ssh agent couldn't recognize the fingerprint).

Sorry to bother you for such simple mistakes, although I wouldn't mind an explanation on why it happened. (I'm using an Ubuntu 16.04.1 desktop to access a CentOS 6.8 server, and I read Ubuntu use to hash server names when it register hosts fingerprints)

Comment: Are you sure you're connecting to `xxxxxx`? That looks fake.

Comment: How can I be sure (except using the host fingerprint)?

Comment: So you actually named your host `xxxxxx`? Maybe you used too many x's, or not enough.

Comment: Uh uh, that's not my real host name ofc.

Comment: @sleuvins ahah that was really funny, dammit. Are you using scp ?

Comment: We have no way of knowing that. You're expected to not use fake information whenever possible. Anyway, you should check carefully for typos.

Comment: I am using scp. Strangely I can scp for a single file, but it's when I do it for a folder that I get troubles.

Comment: Michael, are you saying I should just write down my real server's domain name/IP in a thread where I'm saying that I have ssh connecting trouble? Wouldn't have come to my mind... Anyway, same name works for ssh acces, but not for scp. Or maybe it's just my scp command that I'm screwing up? I'll write it in my question.

Comment: What is the exact `scp` command you are using?

Comment: Re update: `sudo` runs a program here `scp` as user root so it uses user root's `known_hosts` file, not that for your userid. `ssh-agent` has nothing to do with host fingerprints or host keys; it manages your _user_ (client) keys.

Comment: Oh, it totally makes sense now. Thank you. Would you post it as an answer so I can mark it as the solution and close the thread? Edit: isn't it ssh-agent who checks if the received fingerprint matches with one saved in known_hosts files? Or is ssh-agent different from openssh client? (in the case of using openssh ofc)